# how to control access via policy in cfn templates?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I have a policy, defined as cloudformation template below. I want to be able to describe what aws resources , they can create via cfn template. how do i do that? I have attached a sample example below?

```
Type: 'AWS::IAM::Policy'
Properties:
  PolicyName: CFNUsers
  PolicyDocument:
    Version: "2012-10-17"
    Statement:
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - 'cloudformation:Describe*'
          - 'cloudformation:List*'
          - 'cloudformation:Get*'
        Resource: '*'
```

Comment: Sorry, its not clear what you want to do? Whos "they"? What resources? The policy is for what?

Comment: @Marcin - thanks. sorry for the confusion. I was myself , confused on last line above -> "Resource:*", on what this exactly meant. silly mistake . under this , I can list any IAM roles, users or other aws resources and they will have the access to perform the actions listed under Action . so i just need to replace * with the resources or users or roles , i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your policy has three Actions:

```
          - 'cloudformation:Describe*'
          - 'cloudformation:List*'
          - 'cloudformation:Get*'
```

These actions can be performed on all (*) CloudFormation (CFN) stacks, not "any IAM roles, users or other aws resources". This is because only CFN stacks can be acted upon using these three actions.

`AWS::IAM::Policy` is [managed IAM policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_managed-vs-inline.html#customer-managed-policies). Such policies must be **attacked** to IAM user, role or group. This way you give permissions to perform the three  actions on CFN stacks to who/what ever you are going to attach the policy to.